# Flexiforce pressure sensor with positive voltage

Tags: sensor, adc

I recently purchased piezoresistive [Flexiforce pressure sensors](http://www.tekscan.com/flexible-force-sensors) but I´m having some problems connecting it to an A/D converter.

On their website [they show an example of an excitation circuit](http://www.tekscan.com/flexiforce-sample-circuit) but it is using negative voltage which is something I don´t have access to. I need to make a circuit that does pretty much the same thing but with only positive voltage.

This is the circuit they recomend:

[image]

Comment: They have the positive rail connected to the *bottom* of the op-amp?  Grr.  http://opencircuitdesign.com/xcircuit/goodschem/goodschem.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [piezoresistive effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoresistive_effect) just means the resistance of the sensor changes with pressure.  With their circuit, the -5 V supply will be inverted and amplified with the gain varying with the sensor resistance.  The output voltage will vary from 0 to 5 V.

Instead of using a -5 V supply, you could just connect the bottom of the sensor to ground, and connect the positive input of the op-amp to a 2.5 V bias voltage.  Then the voltage at the output would vary from 2.5 to 5 V.

Depending on what you're using it for, you could just [connect it as a voltage divider](http://www.doctronics.co.uk/voltage.htm), and then follow that by an inverting amplifier with an adjustable gain and DC bias so that you can get 0 to 5 V for whatever pressure range you want.

Comment: Thank you. This will work fine. I would give you a vote up but my reputation says I cannot.